# AWS CDK creating multiple stacks in multiple regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have a very large AWS CDK codebase that deploys 16 resources separated in 3 stacks. When i deploy the stacks in a pipeline, they work flawlessly only if i deploy it in us-east-1. However, when i deploy them in us-west-2, some stacks failed, so far the ones that failed are WAF, ACM, and Cloudfront. Lets take WAF for example,

```
ip_set_v4 = wafv2.CfnIPSet(
    self,
    "CLOUDFRONTIPSetv4",
    addresses=ip_v4,
    ip_address_version="IPV4",
    name="ipv4sets",
    scope="CLOUDFRONT",
)
```

when i run the code above, the pipeline will fail and it tells me that deploying a waf stack that creates an ip set with the scope cloudfront can only be done in us-east-1. However, since we deploy it in a single pipeline that contains all 16 resources in 3 stacks, it takes the default region value which is us-west-2 which causes the error.

Is there a way for me to still deploy this pipeline as is (without breaking the stacks in a different pipeline), but force certain resources (WAF, ACM, Cloudfront for example, and who knows what else since we cant finish our pipeline) to be created in us-east-1 but the rest of the resources can be created in other regions all in the same pipeline?

Comment: A single stack can generally only deploy to a single region. You can specify the region in the `env` prop of the stack's constructor. You would need to clarify your question with a bit of code if you want a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the region in stack level but you need to use Environment when instantiating the stack. For example:

```
from aws_cdk import Environment
...

WAFStack(self, "waf", env=Environment(region="us-east-1", account=<aws_account_id>))
```